# No entiendo el scope de node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, scope

Tengo un problema con el escope de node que no logro entender muy bien mi problema radica en que quiero almacenar en un arreglo "rutasexcedidas" los paths de los archivos en una carpeta cualquiera del equipo, pero cuando recorro las carpetas por medio de la función x y los voy almacenando en el arreglo, cuando trato de imprimir mi arreglo por fuera de la funcion no me muestra paths agregados.  No veo mi error espero que alguien me logre ayudar, y explicar. Muchas gracias.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const colors = require("colors");

const rutaArchivo = "C:/Users/UsuarioGastro/Downloads/Documentos"
let rutasExcedidas = [];
//let rutasExcedidas = [1321,32132,1321321,654];
const dbPath = './database.json';

function x(rutaArchivo) {
    //console.log(rutasExcedidas)
    const stats = fs.lstatSync(rutaArchivo);
    if(!stats.isDirectory()){
        //if((rutaArchivo.length-33)+94 >= 260){
            rutasExcedidas.push(rutaArchivo);
        //}
    } else {
        fs.readdir(rutaArchivo, (err, archivos) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            archivos.forEach((archivo) => {
                x(rutaArchivo+"/"+archivo);
            })
        });
    }
}
x(rutaArchivo);
console.log(rutasExcedidas);
```

Comment: estas usando una funcion asincrona dentro de una sincrona... probablemente tu problema es que debes usar `fs.readdirSync` en vez de `fs.readdir`